# ¿Como Guardar el resultado se la consulta select en un label?

Tags: vb.net

**El codigo es el siguiente**

```
 Dim cn4 As New SqlConnection
    cn4.ConnectionString = conexion
    Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand()
    cmd4.CommandText = ("select top 1 id from adquisiciondictamen order by id desc")
    cmd4.Connection = cn4
    cn4.Open()
    Dim dr2 As SqlDataReader
    dr2 = cmd4.ExecuteReader
```

**"mi label es tiene la valiable de idadquisicion*

> Quiero que el resultado de la consulta select sea guardado en un label
>   '¿Como lo hago...? saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos aqui puedes ver un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = "your Connection String"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim query As String = "SELECT SUM(Hours) FROM TimeSheet WHERE StaffID='" &
 cbStaffID.Text & "' AND TimeSheetMonth='" & cbMonth.Text & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
    Try
    con.open
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If myreader.Read() Then
            yourlable.text = myreader.GetValue(0)

        End If
        myreader.Close()
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Estoy adaptando el codigo ( tu ejemplo) al  mio, en breve sabemos el resultado. gracias -Saldos <3

Comment: Adaptado, Muchas gracias tenia 2 dias tratando de hacerlo quedo perfecto

Comment: vale @JacoboRiosAG keep coding, Salud2